# read files and compare particular attribute

Tags: c#, xml

I am a beginner at c #, i have two XML files which i have accessed in one file.
Now i need to read a particular element and its value. So if the value exceeds limit to say 700, it should beep an alarm.

I am using visual studio 2013. the file is as below. this is one file, but if one another same like this having another light value say 1034. Then i need to compare two different values and alert the user that the limit is exceeded.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<MotePacket>
    <ParsedDataElement>
        <Name>amtype</Name>
        <ConvertedValue>11</ConvertedValue>
    </ParsedDataElement>
    <ParsedDataElement>
        <Name>nodeid</Name>
        <ConvertedValue>1</ConvertedValue>
    </ParsedDataElement>
    <ParsedDataElement>
        <Name>parent</Name>
        <ConvertedValue>0</ConvertedValue>
    </ParsedDataElement>
    <ParsedDataElement>
        <Name>group</Name>
        <ConvertedValue>125</ConvertedValue>
    </ParsedDataElement>
    <ParsedDataElement>
        <Name>socketid</Name>
        <ConvertedValue>51</ConvertedValue>
    </ParsedDataElement>
    <ParsedDataElement>
        <Name>board_id</Name>
        <ConvertedValue>132</ConvertedValue>
    </ParsedDataElement>
    <ParsedDataElement>
        <Name>packet_id</Name>
        <ConvertedValue>129</ConvertedValue>
    </ParsedDataElement>
    <ParsedDataElement>
        <Name>voltage</Name>
        <ConvertedValue>2625</ConvertedValue>
    </ParsedDataElement>
    <ParsedDataElement>
        <Name>temp</Name>
        <ConvertedValue>23.127808</ConvertedValue>
    </ParsedDataElement>
    <ParsedDataElement>
        <Name>light</Name>
        <ConvertedValue>128</ConvertedValue>
    </ParsedDataElement>
    <ParsedDataElement>
        <Name>mic</Name>
        <ConvertedValue>272</ConvertedValue>
    </ParsedDataElement>
    <ParsedDataElement>
        <Name>accel_x</Name>
        <ConvertedValue>-160.000000</ConvertedValue>
    </ParsedDataElement>
    <ParsedDataElement>
        <Name>accel_y</Name>
        <ConvertedValue>560.000000</ConvertedValue>
    </ParsedDataElement>
    <ParsedDataElement>
        <Name>mag_x</Name>
        <ConvertedValue>30.790493</ConvertedValue>
    </ParsedDataElement>
    <ParsedDataElement>
        <Name>mag_y</Name>
        <ConvertedValue>30.790493</ConvertedValue>
    </ParsedDataElement>
</MotePacket>
```

Comment: You've said what the broad aim is, but not what's specifically holding you back. Is it loading the files? Extracting the relevant information? Comparing the values?

Comment: hi jon, i have loaded the files successfully , and i can read it on my output window ( textbox) but what i need is to extract the values of the only light parameter, and compare the value  from two XML files to indicate the user that the light exceed the limit. please help me

Comment: its just extracting one perticular element named light !!!! once i could read that rest i can even try. @JonSkeet